# React Native debugger - breakpoints not being hit in code that executes soon after start

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I'm debugging React Native in Chrome, app is running on an Android emulator on localhost.

Breakpoints in componentDidMount() are not being hit, but if I wrap some code in a setTimeout() to delay execution, the debugger hits the breapoint and pauses as expected?!

Comment: This seems to only occur when a file is changed. If you hit "Reload JS" (in the red box) after an error, the breakpoint should be picked up.

Comment: I mentioned this quirk in an issue: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/69#issuecomment-460020438